# Zxing Xamarin-forms Autofocus

Tags: xamarin.forms, zxing, autofocus

I am using Zxing to scan barcode in Xamarin forms App ,
The problem is Autofocus works only once when the scanpage Appeared ,
I tried to add timer as below  Code also not worked ,
and I noted when I change the application and return to it (in scan page ) Auto focus works perfect ,
I also added Button to Autofocus to overlay , it's fired but camera didn't focus
any advise ?

```
 scanPage.AutoFocus();
            TimeSpan ts = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 10, 0);
            Device.StartTimer(ts, () =>
            {
                if (scanPage.IsScanning)
                {
                    scanPage.AutoFocus();
                }
                return true;
            });
```

Comment: bro, why you added this line `scanPage.AutoFocus();`  before the timer starts?

Comment: @AnasAlweish it's one of  my attempts ... can be deleted nothing will change 
do you have any suggestion bro ?

Comment: I have since switched to this library that uses the Google Vision API. Works a lot smoother in my experience: https://github.com/JimmyPun610/BarcodeScanner.XF

Answer (score 0):

Don't use a ScannerPage.
Use their MobileBarcodeScanner.

```
var scanner = new ZXing.Mobile.MobileBarcodeScanner();
var result = await scanner.Scan();
```

From documentation: https://github.com/Redth/ZXing.Net.Mobile#usage

Comment: That's not compatible with Forms, is it?

Comment: What exact? I successfully use ZXing.Mobile.MobileBarcodeScanner in my XF project.

Comment: There's no option to use that object within a Forms page. It can only be a full page object. Or am I missing a hidden feature?